# SQL group by, let null value stay

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have an SQL table for transfer histories like this:

```
ID | Date_out | Date_in
---+----------+----------
1  | 01.01.15 | 
2  | 01.01.15 | 13.05.15
2  | 16.07.14 | 01.01.15
4  | 28.07.15 |
4  | 16.07.14 | 28.07.15
```

You can say that item with ID 2 was given away on 16.07.14 and returned on 01.01.15 and after that it went out again on 01.01.15 and returned back on 13.05.15. So it's in my office.

The item with ID 4 was given away on 16.07.14 and returned on 28.07.15 after that it went out again on 28.07.15. So it's not in my office

**Now I want a list with every Item which is in my office and a list with items which are not in my office.** I have to use Microsoft Access.

```
result 1: Items in my office

ID | Date_out | Date_in
---+----------+----------
2  | 01.01.15 | 13.05.15


result 2: Items outside my office
 ID | Date_out | Date_in
---+----------+----------
1  | 01.01.15 | 
4  | 28.07.15 |
```

The problem is that I have the items multiple times. When I group by ID the empty dates disappear like and I still have multiple items:

```
SELECT 
    table.item_ID,
    table.Date_out, 
    table.Date_in
FROM table 
WHERE table.date_in<Now()
GROUP BY table.item_ID
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you want two queries or one? What is the expected result? Show also your group by approach. You should also say what rdbms you are using(f.e. MySql, Oracle or SQL-Server).

Comment: Can you add the current SQL? I think a Rank/Row_Number would probably sort this.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you're executing, the results you expect, and the results you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you have to store dates as DATES!!

Comment: @Strawberry - 1. Who told you it's not sorted as dates? 2. Why is it *mandatory* to store as dates?

Comment: @Amit because without that information, it's impossible to say what the current status of the item is.

Comment: @Strawberry you're wrong. It's not a great idea not to use dates, but it's not impossible. And again, why are you assuming it's not stored as dates? Is it because of the way the output looks in the question? I surely hope you have a better reason

Comment: @Strawberry this is just an example as text. The value is stored as dates in Acces, but I think I will change that and store them as unix-time

Comment: @noctua We can only go on the information provided. If you provide misleading information, you may well receive a misleading answer.

Answer (score 0):

another solution for your problem

```
SELECT 
id,
CASE
    WHEN
        SUM(CASE WHEN date_in IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    THEN 'out'
    ELSE 'in'
END
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID INT NOT NULL
,Date_out DATE NOT NULL
,Date_in DATE NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,date_out)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1  ,'2015-01-01',NULL),
(2  ,'2015-01-01','2015-05-13'),
(2  ,'2014-07-16','2015-01-01'),
(4  ,'2015-07-28',NULL),
(4  ,'2014-07-16','2015-07-28');

SELECT x.id on_loan 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT id, MAX(date_out) max_date_out FROM my_table GROUP BY id) y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.max_date_out = x.date_out 
 WHERE date_in IS NULL;
+---------+
| on_loan |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       4 |
+---------+

SELECT x.id in_stock 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date_out) max_date_out FROM my_table GROUP BY id) y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.max_date_out = x.date_out 
  WHERE date_in IS NOT NULL;
+----------+
| in_stock |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
```

or, less useful...

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN date_in IS NULL THEN x.id END) on_loan
     , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN date_in IS NOT NULL THEN x.id END) in_stock 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id, MAX(date_out) max_date_out FROM my_table GROUP BY id) y 
    ON y.id = x.id AND y.max_date_out = x.date_out;
+---------+----------+
| on_loan | in_stock |
+---------+----------+
| 1,4     | 2        |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Read the details of the question. MS-ACCESS, not MySQL